# Warning: `Reference` should not be used outside of a `Manager` component in CoreUI dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I'm getting the following warning when I navigate to dashboard!!

```
Warning: `Reference` should not be used outside of a `Manager` component.
```

Comment: did you updated dependency on your own ? if yes then update caused this..

Comment: most probably `reactstrap` caused it... as they are implementing hooks in newer releases..

Comment: @Excalibur perfect, I downgraded the reactstrap v8.0.0 to v7.1.0 and it's worked !